# How to elide copy when chaining?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I am creating a class of chaining-type, such as the small example below. It seems that when chaining member functions, then the copy constructor is invoked. Is there a way to get rid of the copy constructor call? In my toy example below, it is obvious that I'm only dealing with temporaries and thus there "should" (maybe not by the standards, but logically) be an elision. The second best choice, to copy elision, would be for the move constructor to be called, but this is not the case.

```
class test_class {
    private:
    int i = 5;
    public:
    test_class(int i) : i(i) {}
    test_class(const test_class& t) {
        i = t.i;
        std::cout << "Copy constructor"<< std::endl;
    }
    test_class(test_class&& t) {
        i = t.i;
        std::cout << "Move constructor"<< std::endl;
    }
    auto& increment(){
        i++;
        return *this;
    }
};
int main()
{
    //test_class a{7};
    //does not call copy constructor
    auto b = test_class{7};
    //calls copy constructor
    auto b2 = test_class{7}.increment();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Some clarifications.
1. This does not depend on optimization level.
2. In my real code, I have more complex (e.g. heap allocated) objects than ints

Comment: Which optimization level do you use for compiling?

Comment: `auto b = test_class{7};` doesn't call copy constructor because it's really equivalent to `test_class b{7};` and compilers are smart enough to recognize this case and can therefore easily elide any copying. The same can't be done for `b2`.

Comment: In the shown example, there might not actual be any or much difference between move and copy and not everyone is aware of this. If you stuck something like a big vector in there it might be a different matter. Normally move only makes sense for resource using types (like using a lot of heap mem., etc.) - is that the case here ?

Comment: The example looks contrived. Do you actually have I/O (`std::cout`) in your copy ctor? Without it the copy should be optimized away.

Comment: @rustyx, remove the std::cout and make the copy constructor explicit. This demonstrates that the copy elision is not std::cout dependent.

Comment: @DDaniel what are you talking about? An `explicit` copy ctor won't compile.

Comment: @rustyx You suggested that the I/O operation is what's stopping the copy elision. One easy way to check if this is true is by removing I/O and making the copy constructor explicit. If you do that you will notice that It still fails to compile. If you also remove `auto b2 = test_class{7}.increment();`, then it can compile because it is able to elide the copy in `auto b = test_class{7};`.

Comment: I said nothing about elision, I said *optimized away*. Guaranteed *elision* in your case is not possible, not even in the upcoming C++ standard.

Comment: @rustyx, okay, I misunderstood you. The above example was a simple toy example. In the real code I have more advanced data structures in the class, and I have more advanced chaining functions than a simple increment.

Answer (score 7):

1. Partial answer (it doesn't construct `b2` in place, but turns the copy construction into a move construction): You can overload the `increment` member function on the value category of the associated instance:

   ```
   auto& increment() & {
       i++;
       return *this;
   }

   auto&& increment() && {
       i++;
      return std::move(*this);
   }
   ```

   This causes

   ```
   auto b2 = test_class{7}.increment();
   ```

   to move-construct `b2` because `test_class{7}` is a temporary, and the `&&` overload of `test_class::increment` is called.
2. For a true in-place construction (i.e. not even a move construction), you can turn all special and non-special member functions into `constexpr` versions. Then, you can do

   ```
   constexpr auto b2 = test_class{7}.increment();
   ```

   and you neither a move nor a copy construction to pay for. This is, obviously, possible for the simple `test_class`, but not for a more general scenario that doesn't allow for `constexpr` member functions.

Comment: The second alternative also makes `b2` non-modifiable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Good point. I guess `constinit` would be the way to go there.

Comment: What is the purpose of the ampersands after the function name? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @PhilipNelson they are [ref-qualifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions) and can dictate what `this` is just the same as `const` member functions

Answer (score 1):

Basically, assigning a [reference](/questions/tagged/reference) to a [value](/questions/tagged/value) requires invoking a constructor, i.e. a *copy* or a *move*. This is different from [copy-elision](/questions/tagged/copy-elision) where it is known on both sides of the function to be the same distinct object. Also a [reference](/questions/tagged/reference) can refer to a shared object much like a pointer.

---

The simplest way is probably to make the copy constructor being fully optimized away. The value setting is already optimized by the compiler, it is just the `std::cout` that cannot be optimized away.

```
test_class(const test_class& t) = default;
```

*(or just remove both the copy and move constructor)*

[live example](https://godbolt.org/z/R5BXwI)

---

Since your issue is basicly with the reference, a solution is probably not returning a reference to the object if you want to stop copying in this way.

```
  void increment();
};

auto b = test_class{7};//does not call copy constructor
b.increment();//does not call copy constructor
```

---

A third method is just relying on *copy elision* in the first place - however this requires a rewrite or encapsulation of the operation into one function and thus avoiding the issue altogether (I'm aware this may not be what you want, but could be a solution to other users):

```
auto b2 = []{test_class tmp{7}; tmp.increment().increment().increment(); return tmp;}(); //<-- b2 becomes 10 - copy constructor not called
```

---

A fourth method is using a move instead, either invoked explicit

```
auto b2 = std::move(test_class{7}.increment());
```

*or* as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58657464/2261538).

Comment: @O'Neil was thinking of another case - ty, corrected